# How can I have JProfiler open source code in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jprofiler

I use JProfiler 8.1.4 and I have it integrated with IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3.

I have a JProfiler session for profiling JBoss using the `standalone_jprofiler.bat` script like this:

[image]

Now, when I want to go to the source code for some method, JProfiler uses a (minimal) internal file viewer instead of using IntelliJ.

I would assume that the source code linking works fine when the profiling is initiated by the IntelliJ plugin, but in my case I don't know what run configuration to create in IntelliJ for `standalone_jprofiler.bat`.

So finally, my question is: Is it possible to see the code in IntelliJ when the profiling is initiated from the standalone JProfiler application?

One more piece of information: In this case I want the profiling to be activated immediately on startup.

I apologize in advance if this is too simple or silly. I've used JProfiler for just one day and googling didn't yield any relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to see the code in IntelliJ when the profiling is initiated from the standalone JProfiler application

No, that is not possible, you have to start the profiling session from  IDEA to get source code navigation in the IDE.

Another possibility is to save a snapshot in JProfiler and open that snapshot in IDEA (via File->Open File). If the JProfiler plugin is installed in IDEA, the snapshot will then be opened with source code navigation in the IDE.

Comment: Opening the snapshot from IntelliJ is a good idea, but it's currently broken. I've submitted a bug report for that. The showAndGetOk() method is for modeless dialogs only
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The showAndGetOk() method is for modeless dialogs only
 at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1590)
 at com.jprofiler.integrations.idea.snapshot.b.show(b.java:8)
 at com.jprofiler.integrations.idea.snapshot.f.run(f.java:3)

Comment: Thank you for reporting this, we will fix this shortly,